# Azure Disaster Recovery

Tags: azure, backup, disaster-recovery

We have on premises VMware Servers and configured scheduled VM backup in Azure Cloud Server. Could you please someone explain if our on premises hardware crashed, is it possible to run those backups from Azure cloud like secondary server to avoid down time.

Comment: Please add more details to your question like adding error messages and what have you done so far to understand the problem

Answer (score 0):

If you replicate your on-premises VMs to Azure, in the event of disaster you can trigger failover with single click in the Azure portal, or you can use Site Recovery PowerShell to trigger a failover. Reference URL - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/site-recovery-faq#is-failover-automatic

For your information, see this link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/site-recovery-backup-interoperability AFAIK, this is supported only in Azure to Azure scenario.